# How to get authenticate with the squareup using backend golang?

Tags: security, go, oauth-2.0

In sqaureup application `Aplication_name` in oauth option there is a redirect url Which will redirect a given url with the QueryString code. While I'm hitting `https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID` this url in the browser then it will redirect me to a given url in oauth with attached code. And  then to take a `access_token` you have to give a `POST` request to given url `https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/token` with the body

```
{
  "client_id": "YOUR_APPLICATION_ID",
  "client_secret": "YOUR_APPLICATION_SECRET",
  "code": "M-Q7k-N0Emx_3cBqwbVLTQ",
  "redirect_uri": "YOUR_REDIRECT_URI"
}
```

I do it same and send By method `POST` to this url with json data but it will gives me the error:-

```
{
 "message": "Not Authorized",
 "type": "service.not_authorized"
}
```

The Golang Code I'm using for this is :-

```
func Token(c *gin.Context) {
 code := c.Query("code") // code be something like:-sq0cgp-wLVQt5HOLfug6xiVdmCDCf
 splitCode := strings.Split(code, "-")
 token := models.PostToken{
    ClientID:     "YOUR_APPLICATION_ID",
    ClientSecret: "YOUR_APPLICATION_SECRET",
    Code:         splitCode[1],
    RedirectUri:  c.Request.Host + c.Request.URL.RequestURI(),
 }
 bindData, err := json.Marshal(token)
 if err != nil {
    panic(err)
 }
   var jsonStr = []byte(string(bindData))
   url := "https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/token"
   req, err := http.Post(url, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
   fmt.Println(req, err)
}
```

Models struct:-

```
type PostToken struct {
  ClientID     string `json:"client_id" bson:"client_id"`
  ClientSecret string `json:"client_secret" bson:"client_secret"`
  Code         string `json:"code" bson:"code"`
  RedirectUri  string `json:"redirect_uri" bson:"redirect_uri"`
}
```

Comment: 1) `RedirectUri` is missing the scheme ("https://" presumably). 2) This is not a [standard token request](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.3). Standard requests use form data, not JSON, include a grant_type field, and no client secret. Double check the documentation and make sure you're supposed to send JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some points I mentioned:-

- First check your application Id.
- In second parameter `ClientSecret` you have to use Oauth Application Secret key Which you will got from the application dashboard -> Oauth option.
- In `Code` you don't have send the split code send simple string code value which your getting in the variable name `code`.
- Fourth parameter is optional as the documentation says [here](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/oauth#post-token).

Then you will got what you want :D.